# When designing a CLI, how does one indicate that FILE is required (either by stdin or by argument)

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse, manage.py

Best is to go over an example.

I want my CLI to be able to be run both ways, how do I correctly convey this in the help docs?

```
Usage:
  my-cli import FILE
  my-cli import [FILE] (in case where stdin is used only)
```

e.g.

`my-cli import test.xlsx`

`my-cli import < test.xlsx`

In the second scenario the FILE flag is not being passed (so requiring FILE causes an error in my current implementation).

Relaxing the constraint causes the system to work as intended except that now it is possible to not pass in a file AND not to pass in via stdin.

For more context, I am working on a Django Management CLI (syntax follows argparse closely). Here is some code showing where FILE is scene as optional.

```
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(
            title='commands', dest='command', help='command help')
        subparsers.required = True

        parser_import = subparsers.add_parser('import', help='import help')

        parser_import.add_argument('FILE', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=sys.stdin)
```

The `nargs='?'` argument causes the help to look like:

```
usage: manage.py my-cli import [-h] [FILE]

positional arguments:
  FILE

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

What I am looking for is to adjust my code somehow so that the produced `./manage.py my-cli import --help` displays something more sane. Also that not passing anything via the stdin or passing in a file throws an error.

Comment: I found that a '-' can be used to signify stdin must be read. So I can make it a required field, then ensure the user uses a - to pass into the stdin.

Comment: IMO, there's no reason to allow the path as a parameter.  Always read from stdin.  Simpler is better.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Won't that make it potentially more complex for the user though. An option of `my-cli import FILE` is more simple than `my-cli import - < FILE` or `my-cli import < FILE` to the user.

Comment: It is true that `my-cli < FILE` is one character longer than `my-clii FILE`.  IMO, that one character of additional complexity is not saved by the additional logic.  But `cmd | my-cli` is simpler than `cmd | my-cli -`, and it is impossible to know which is the more common use case.  The latter is very likely to be more common. 
 Everything is simpler if you just read from stdin.

Comment: In my apposing opinion, reading from STDIN is only required when the file system is abstracted away or inconvenient to use and is a special case for use with automated scripts, etc. Most UNIX tools accept FILE as a parameter and also allow STDIN for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

- Simple is better than complex
- Explicit is better than implicit

Keeping those two concepts in mind:

1. Help will look something like this:

```
usage: manage.py my_cli import [-h] FILE

positional arguments:
  FILE        path to file, otherwise if "-", read from STDIN

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

This way, FILE is always a requirement and if absent an error would be thrown. And '-' is an explicit placeholder for argument where the stdin will be piped to.

---

The Django code would look something like this as a result:

```py
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(
            title='commands', dest='command', help='command help')
        subparsers.required = True
        parser_import = subparsers.add_parser('import', help='import help')
        parser_import.add_argument('FILE', help='path to file, otherwise if "-", read from STDIN')
```

And a context manager that could describe the functionality of 'path to file, otherwise if "-", read from STDIN':

```py
@contextlib.contextmanager
def file_ctx(filename: str) -> IO[bytes]:
    if filename == '-':
        yield io.BytesIO(sys.stdin.buffer.read())
    else:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            yield f
```