# Is there a convention if GNU-like CLI should consider stdin or file passed as arg to come first?

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, posix, command-line-arguments, conventions

I'm designing a CLI that should accept input in two ways:

1. From stdin: `cat in_stdin.csv | csv2parquet -o out.parquet`
2. From one or multiple files passed as explicit argument `csv2parquet in1.csv in2.csv -o out.parquet`

Now the question arises how to handle the case when a user tries to use both ways of giving input:

```bash
cat in_stdin.csv | csv2parquet in1.csv in2.csv -o out.parquet
```

Is there a weak or strong convention about the order in which an experienced developer would expect these inputs to be dealt with? Let's assume this CLI wants to behave according to GNU/POSIX guidelines.

For instance, it's reasonable to assume that the `in1.csv` will be considered to come before `in2.csv`.

But I don't have a clear intuition whether `in_stdin.csv` would be expected to come before `in1.csv` or after `in2.csv`. The third option is that such mixed inputs are conventionally avoided and should thus be disallowed.

A fourth option would be to not accept `stdin` implicitly, but to require it to be specified either as `/dev/stdin` or `-`. This would be the most general solution as it would allow arbitrary orders to be specified by the user, e.g. making `stdin` come in the middle: `cat in_stdin.csv | csv2parquet in1.csv - in2.csv`.

I tried to read around but couldn't find clear guidelines on this, neither from [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces) nor [POSIX](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467531/when-designing-a-cli-how-does-one-indicate-that-file-is-required-either-by-std) is only superficially similar.

Comment: Options (i.e. `-o out.parquet`) come before positional arguments (e.g. `in1.csv`, `in2.csv`)

Comment: I'm in a similar position of looking for best practice when reading CSV (or other non-simple-line-based) files and I'm curious if you have considered the case if a user tries `cat in_stdin1.csv in_stdin2.csv | csv2parquet -o out.parquet` -- assuming your CSV files have a field name header.

Answer (score 1):

Common and TTBOMK universal practice is your fourth option: in a program that offers both methods of input, if you specify NO file arguments/operands it reads from stdin, but if you specify ANY file argument(s)/operand(s) it reads only the file(s) specified and does not automatically add stdin anywhere. Whether a filename consisting of a single hyphen means stdin varies; this is common but NOT universal.

Not all programs offer the choice; e.g. `cmp x y` won't read from stdin if the filenames are omitted and `tr` only reads from stdin never from a named file.

Not all programs read multiple specified files in any particular order: `cmp - x` or `cmp x -` reads the named file and stdin concurrently, neither one is 'before' the other.

The optionality of `-` is implied, though not called out, in [XBD 1.4](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_04) under OPERANDS: "[it] is explicitly stated ... if an operand naming a file can be specified as '-', which means to use [stdin]". The fact it needs to be explicitly stated means it is isn't required.

Similarly the next subsection (STDIN) references that for 'many' utilities (implying not all), stdin can be used "in the same manner [as an input file]" but it does not mention this is an XOR choice. AFAICT that is specified only for each utility, e.g. your example of [`cat`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html#tag_20_13):

> ... If no file operands are specified, the standard input shall be used. If a file is '-', the cat utility shall read from the standard input at that point in the sequence. The cat utility shall not close and reopen standard input when it is referenced in this way, but shall accept multiple occurrences of '-' as a file operand.

> The standard input shall be used only if no file operands are specified, or if a file operand is '-'.

The [GNU implementation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cat-invocation.html#cat-invocation) describes this more concisely (emphasis added):

> cat copies each file (‘-’ means standard input), or standard input **if** none are given ....